# Is there a way to populate a select field with all possible one-to-one relations in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm trying to make it so the Admin Panel of my website will auto spit out a drop down list for one to one relationship fields...

I know drop downs are made like this in blade templates...

```
{{ Form::select('list', ['Value' => 'Display']) }}
```

So I just need a way to add the Eloquent query to populate that array in that format... Any ideas? Is there an out of the box way of doing this? I can't seem to find documentation on it in the Laravel Forms & one to one documentation...

I would imagine I could do something like this, and through the magic of Laravel, it would work...

```
{{ Form::select('list', MyModel::where('enabled', true)->pluck('title', 'id')) }}
```

Right now I do this by passing in the list to the view, but I'm wondering if there is a native way to do it...

```
  public function get_option_list()
  {
    return MyModel::where('enabled', true)->pluck('title', 'id');
  }

  public function create()
  {
    return view('admin.myview.create')->with('list', $this->get_option_list());
  }
```

and in blade...

```
{{ Form::select('list_id', $list) }}
```

I use Laravel 5.3.

Comment: Did you try `{{ Form::select('size', MyModel::where('enabled', true)->get()) }}`? What was the result?

Comment: Gave an error because the blade form wasn't using MyModel. I guess I could have it use it...

Comment: I think you are doing that right way. however, if you are looking for passing the model to blade you can check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007639/laravel-5-call-a-model-function-in-a-blade-view

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right except that you missed it here

```
 public function get_option_list()
  {
    return MyModel::where('enabled', true)->pluck('title', 'id')->toArray();
  }
```

Everything remains the same

```
public function create()
  {
    return view('admin.myview.create')->with('list', $this->get_option_list());
  }
```

And your blade

```
{{ Form::select('list_id', $list) }}
```