# how to access function defined in model to view?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

my laravel model funciton :

```php
   public function isAdminOrSuperAdmin()
    {
        return $this->role() == config('custom_config.constants.user_types.SUPER_ADMIN') 
               || $this->role() == config('custom_config.constants.user_types.ADMIN');
    }
```

i try to access in view :

```html
@if($user->isAdminOrSuperAdmin())
        <a class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-top: 
           -10px;margin-bottom: 5px" href="{!! route('admin.users.create') !!}">
            Add New
        </a>
@endif
```

but it show error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::isAdminOrSuperAdmin does not exist. (View:/resources/views/admin/users/index.blade.php)

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::isAdminOrSuperAdmin does not exist. (View:/resources/views/admin/users/index.blade.php)

This means, you are trying to call a method of your model on a `Collection` instance instead of an actual `User` model instance.

When querying several items from your database, Laravel returns an instance of the `Collection` class that contains all the resulting model objects.

Maybe you are doing something like this:

```php
public function aCoolFunction()
{
    $user = User::where('column', 'value')
                  ->get(); // <-----

    return view('my_view')->with('user', $user);
}
```

The [`get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-get) method returns a `Collection`, not a single element.

Try the [`first()`](https://laravel.com/docs/collections#method-first) instead:

```php
public function aCoolFunction()
{
    $user = User::where('column', 'value')
                  ->first(); // <-----

    return view('my_view')->with('user', $user);
}
```

Now in your view the `$user` variable will actually hold and instance of your `User` model user in which the `isAdminOrSuperAdmin()` method is defined,  and not a collection of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is the best way but you can pass the function to view using your controller :

in your controller :

```
public function index(User $user)
{
    $ModelFunction = $user->yourModelFunction();
    return View('test',compact('user','ModelFunction'));
}
```

And in your View :

```
{{ $ModelFunction }}
```

Answer (score -1):

you must call function like this:

```
@if(is_admin_or_super_admin())
```

Comment: i did..but its show errors : ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Call to undefined function isAdminOrSuperAdmin() (View:

Comment: initially i tried using this method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007639/laravel-5-call-a-model-function-in-a-blade-view