# laravel 5.8 edit function with model instance

Tags: laravel

```
public function edit(EduLevel $eduLevel)
    {
        dd($eduLevel->name);
         return view('adm.edulevel.edit',compact('eduLevel'));
    }


Route::resource('edulevel','EduLevelController'); //web.php
```

with resource route 
how to get eduLevel to view with model instance laravel. in previous i call with parme parameter id and use find() method to get data..
from this sample - https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-crud-create-read-update-delete-tutorial-for-beginnersexample.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the question but I will just guess that you have a route that accepts a parameter that you you expect it to be the model inside your function.

You need to create a route like this one:

```
Route::get('/edit/{eduLevel}', 'SomeController@edit');
```

Notice the same name for the variable, this is important otherwise you will get only the `id`, `slug` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your path name also have the same name for route segment name.

so your route path should be like this.

```
Route::get('/edit/{variablename}', 'ControllerName@edit');
```

your controller function logic should be like this.

```
public function edit(EduLevel $variablename)
{
     return view('adm.edulevel.edit',compact('variablename'));
}
```

> So make sure your variable name in route and in controller function
>   should be same.

For more information, you can read [Route Model Binding in laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-model-binding)

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem (almost).

I wanted to call a controller method in the view. So I should pass the model from controller to view.
How to pass model from controller to view?
I found this [[Laravel 5 call a model function in a blade view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007639/laravel-5-call-a-model-function-in-a-blade-view]) but using `->withModel($model);` to pass the model from controller to view and `{{$model->someFunction()}}` to call the method in the view is not working.

Any advice please?